# Redirect application's graphical output in Windows Vista/7 (with DWM)

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, aero, dwm

I want to create a desktop manager that takes informations of all running applications including states and screenshots to display and manipulate them in my virtual space (probably in 3D). It can be considered as another layer of abstraction on top of Windows itself.

Because many native Windows Vista/7 features like Flip 3D and Live Thumbnails are able to show each window's activities in real-time e.g. video keeps playing in taskbar's thumbnail, I think DWM allows an application to redirect its output to somewhere else or some special processes are able to collect other applications' graphical outputs (maybe of child processes only). Has Microsoft released a set of public APIs to do so? If not, is it technically possible? And is it easier if I limit my scope to just .NET applications with WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [DwmRegisterThumbnail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969521%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and the DWM will draw the live thumbnail inside your window.

I think there's no supported way to get that data and manipulate it yourself but there are some hacks out there but I never used them myself.

Comment: That works fine for thumbnails. But there's still the question of how Flip3D (Win+Tab), or Switcher (http://insentient.net/) manages to draw window contents

Comment: This is a little late, but in case anyone's still interested - the MSDN article about DWM thumbnails at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969541(v=vs.85).aspx states that these thumbnails cannot be used to get effects like Flip3D.

Incidentally, I have found a DLL dwmredir.dll and looked at its exported functions, and I think that dwmredir.dll is responsible in part for redirecting the window drawing to internal buffers.